# Create a recursion mixin scss

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a recursion @mixin. The mixin has the task to append a selector from a given list and apply a CSS rules. The result of this has to look like this:

```
[data-tag]:not([conref]) {
 border: dashed 2px #2999d1; 
}
[data-tag]:not([conref])[nodeid] {
border: dashed 2px #2999d1; 
}
[data-tag]:not([conref])[nodeid][draggable] {
  border: dashed 2px #2999d1; 
}
[data-tag]:not([conref])[nodeid][draggable][class] {
    border: dashed 2px #2999d1; 
}
```

The @mixin which I have created looks like this:

```
@mixin set-border-to-selectors($list, $item){
    @if false == (index($list, $item)){
        @error "Fail: #{$item} not in list: #{$list}";
    }
    @else{
        $index: index($list, $item);
        @debug "index: #{$index}";
        $item: nth($list, $index);
        &[#{$item}]{
            @include set-data-tag-border;
            @if($index + 1 <= length($list)){
                $item: nth($list, $index + 1);
                @include set-border-to-selectors($list, $item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I use the function it works pretty well.

```
@mixin show-data-tag-border{
    $data-tag-list: (#{$id}, draggable, class);
    $data-tag-list-two: (#{$id}, #{$conref}, class);

    &[data-tag]:not([#{$conref}]){
        @include set-data-tag-border;
        @include set-border-to-selectors($data-tag-list, #{$id});
    }
    &[data-tag]{
        @include set-border-to-selectors($data-tag-list-two, #{$id});
    }
```

But the second call of the set-border-to-selector function throws an error, because the $index in the recusion @mixin does not contain a number. It is empty.

I call the function from `p{@include show-data-tag-border;}` and the border will be set in `@mixin set-data-tag-border{border: solid 1px black}`. And this two variables:
    `$id: id;
    $conref: conref;`

Is there something wrong what I do not see or is this approach wrong to create an recursion in SCSS? I won't use this function only one time and write one or more similar function below to accomplish this.

Comment: There's not enough code here to get this to compile (missing variables, mixin references, etc.)

Comment: for the border I use `@mixin set-data-tag-border{
 border: dashed 2px #2999d1;
}`and the calling function could be something like this `p{@include show-data-tag-border;}`

Comment: So update your question.  It is inconvenient for us to have to piece things together.  For all we know, the way you've defined them is part of the problem.

Comment: Still not what I meant.  If it can't compile on [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/), there is not enough code here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was the declaration of the list elements. I have to make tick marks. 
So instead of this:

```
$data-tag-list: (#{$id}, draggable, class);
$data-tag-list-two: (#{$id}, #{$conref}, class);
```

I have to enclose every element in the list with tick marks:

```
$data-tag-list: ('#{$id}', 'draggable', 'class');
$data-tag-list-two: ('#{$id}', '#{$conref}', 'class');
```

and it works!

Thank you hon2a for your help!

Here is the full code for check up:

```css
$id: id;
$conref: conref;

@mixin set-data-tag-border{border: solid 1px black}

@mixin set-border-to-selectors($list, $item){
    @if false == (index($list, $item)){
        @error "Fail: #{$item} not in list: #{$list}";
    }
    @else{
        $index: index($list, $item);
        @debug "index: #{$index}";
        $item: nth($list, $index);
        &[#{$item}]{
            @include set-data-tag-border;
            @if($index + 1 <= length($list)){
                $item: nth($list, $index + 1);
                @include set-border-to-selectors($list, $item);
            }
        }
    }
}

@mixin show-data-tag-border{
    $data-tag-list: ('#{$id}', 'draggable', 'class');
    $data-tag-list-two: ('#{$id}', '#{$conref}', 'class');

    &[data-tag]:not([#{$conref}]){
        @include set-data-tag-border;
        @include set-border-to-selectors($data-tag-list, #{$id});
    }
    &[data-tag]{
        @include set-border-to-selectors($data-tag-list-two, #{$id});
    }
}

p{@include show-data-tag-border;}
```

Comment: This is exactly why we expect people to provide all of the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Next time I will do it directly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna try to repair your code, as it's too big. Recursion should work just fine like this:

```
@mixin set-borders ($list, $index: 1) {
    @if $index <= length($list) {
        @if $index == 1 {
            &#{nth($list, $index)} {
                @include set-borders($list, $index + 1);
            }
        } @else {
            &,
            &#{nth($list, $index)} {
                @include set-borders($list, $index + 1);
            }
        }
    } @else {
        // ... (set the required properties)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works also one time. On the second call the `#{nth($list, $index)}` returns all attributes, which are in the list and not a number. Very weird in my opinion.

Comment: Then there's some problem with your environment. [My code works](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBBQwP?editors=010) (click on the "eye" icon to see compiled CSS).